# How to print elements of array that start with a particular number?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a Numpy array

```
a= [[[ 6, -1, -1]],

       [[ 8, -1,  3]],

       [[10,  1,  1]],

       [[10, -1, -1]],

       [[10,  1, -1]]]
```

I wish to retain only those rows that start with 10; so I wish my output array to be

```
a_out= [[[10,  1,  1]],

           [[10, -1, -1]],

           [[10,  1, -1]]]
```

I'm trying to iterate over the first element of the array to do so but if I try `a[0,0:]` or `a[0:,0]` I get the entire row or column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a boolean mask:

```
>>> arr
array([[[ 6, -1, -1]],

       [[ 8, -1,  3]],

       [[10,  1,  1]],

       [[10, -1, -1]],

       [[10,  1, -1]]])
>>> mask = arr[:,:,0] == 10
>>> arr[mask]
array([[[10,  1,  1]],

       [[10, -1, -1]],

       [[10,  1, -1]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `a` is a numpy array instead of a Python list. Then you can use this:

```
a[a[:,:,0] == 10]
```

where the inner one is a bool list to select rows.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a list and not an array you can do:

```
filter(lambda x: x[0][0] == 10, a)
```

Comment: I can see that, what he posted is not an array though